# C# Timer won't update in a form

Tags: c#, forms, timer, clock

I'm trying to make a clock using a form in C# but because the UI thread is disabling me from using while loops and stuff like that inside the UI thread I'm using a timer to update every half a second to update a label which in turn updates when the time changes. It's currently set to "00 00 00" and updates once when the program loads to the current digital time. (I update every half a second to avoid the clock being out of sync with the real time clock) My issue is that even though I'm using the timer it only updates once rather than updating the label every half a second. I'm pretty sure I have the code right but maybe not in the right places.

Here's my code:

**MainForm.Designer.cs:**

```
using System;
namespace alarmClock
{
partial class MainForm
{
    System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing) {
            if (components != null) {
                components.Dispose();
            }
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    public void setHourTime() {
        setHour.Text = MainForm.setH.ToString();
        if(MainForm.setH < 10) {
            setHour.Text = "0" + MainForm.setH.ToString();
        }
        if(MainForm.setH > 24) {
            MainForm.setH=0;
            setHour.Text = "0" + MainForm.setH.ToString();
        }
    }
    public void setMinuteTime() {
        setMinute.Text = MainForm.setM.ToString();
        if(MainForm.setM < 10) {
            setMinute.Text = "0" + MainForm.setM.ToString();
        }
        if(MainForm.setM > 60) {
            MainForm.setM=0;
            setMinute.Text = "0" + MainForm.setM.ToString();
        }
    }
    public void setSecondTime() {
        setSecond.Text = MainForm.setS.ToString();
        if(MainForm.setS < 10) {
            setSecond.Text = "0" + MainForm.setS.ToString();
        }
        if(MainForm.setS > 60) {
            MainForm.setS=0;
            setSecond.Text = "0" + MainForm.setS.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(MainForm));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
        this.minute = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.hour = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.second = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.checkboxTime = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox();
        this.delTime = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.tableLayoutPanel2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
        this.tableLayoutPanel3 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
        this.setHour = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.setMinute = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.setSecond = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.tableLayoutPanel4 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
        this.subHour = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.addHour = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.subMin = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.addMin = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.subSec = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.addSec = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.setTime = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
        this.addTime = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.clockTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
        this.tableLayoutPanel2.SuspendLayout();
        this.tableLayoutPanel3.SuspendLayout();
        this.tableLayoutPanel4.SuspendLayout();
        this.setTime.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // tableLayoutPanel1
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.tableLayoutPanel1, "tableLayoutPanel1");
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.minute, 1, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.hour, 0, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.second, 2, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Name = "tableLayoutPanel1";
        // 
        // minute
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.minute, "minute");
        this.minute.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        this.minute.Name = "minute";
        // 
        // hour
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.hour, "hour");
        this.hour.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        this.hour.Name = "hour";
        // 
        // second
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.second, "second");
        this.second.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        this.second.Name = "second";
        // 
        // checkboxTime
        // 
        this.checkboxTime.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Silver;
        resources.ApplyResources(this.checkboxTime, "checkboxTime");
        this.checkboxTime.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        this.checkboxTime.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.checkboxTime.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
                                resources.GetString("checkboxTime.Items"),
                                resources.GetString("checkboxTime.Items1")});
        this.checkboxTime.Name = "checkboxTime";
        this.checkboxTime.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.CheckboxTimeSelectedIndexChanged);
        // 
        // delTime
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.delTime, "delTime");
        this.delTime.Name = "delTime";
        this.delTime.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.delTime.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.DelTimeClick);
        // 
        // tableLayoutPanel2
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.tableLayoutPanel2, "tableLayoutPanel2");
        this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel3, 0, 1);
        this.tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel4, 0, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel2.Name = "tableLayoutPanel2";
        // 
        // tableLayoutPanel3
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.tableLayoutPanel3, "tableLayoutPanel3");
        this.tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(this.setHour, 0, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(this.setMinute, 1, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(this.setSecond, 2, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel3.Name = "tableLayoutPanel3";
        // 
        // setHour
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.setHour, "setHour");
        this.setHour.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        this.setHour.Name = "setHour";
        // 
        // setMinute
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.setMinute, "setMinute");
        this.setMinute.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        this.setMinute.Name = "setMinute";
        // 
        // setSecond
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.setSecond, "setSecond");
        this.setSecond.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        this.setSecond.Name = "setSecond";
        // 
        // tableLayoutPanel4
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.tableLayoutPanel4, "tableLayoutPanel4");
        this.tableLayoutPanel4.Controls.Add(this.subHour, 0, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel4.Controls.Add(this.addHour, 1, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel4.Controls.Add(this.subMin, 2, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel4.Controls.Add(this.addMin, 3, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel4.Controls.Add(this.subSec, 4, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel4.Controls.Add(this.addSec, 5, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel4.Name = "tableLayoutPanel4";
        // 
        // subHour
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.subHour, "subHour");
        this.subHour.Name = "subHour";
        this.subHour.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.subHour.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.SubHourClick);
        // 
        // addHour
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.addHour, "addHour");
        this.addHour.Name = "addHour";
        this.addHour.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.addHour.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.AddHourClick);
        // 
        // subMin
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.subMin, "subMin");
        this.subMin.Name = "subMin";
        this.subMin.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.subMin.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.SubMinClick);
        // 
        // addMin
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.addMin, "addMin");
        this.addMin.Name = "addMin";
        this.addMin.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.addMin.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.AddMinClick);
        // 
        // subSec
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.subSec, "subSec");
        this.subSec.Name = "subSec";
        this.subSec.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.subSec.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.SubSecClick);
        // 
        // addSec
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.addSec, "addSec");
        this.addSec.Name = "addSec";
        this.addSec.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.addSec.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.AddSecClick);
        // 
        // setTime
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.setTime, "setTime");
        this.setTime.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Silver;
        this.setTime.Controls.Add(this.addTime);
        this.setTime.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel2);
        this.setTime.Name = "setTime";
        this.setTime.TabStop = false;
        // 
        // addTime
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this.addTime, "addTime");
        this.addTime.Name = "addTime";
        this.addTime.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.addTime.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.AddTimeClick);
        // 
        // clockTimer
        // 
        this.clockTimer.Enabled = true;
        this.clockTimer.Interval = 500;
        this.clockTimer.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.ClockTimerTick);
        // 
        // MainForm
        // 
        resources.ApplyResources(this, "$this");
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;
        this.Controls.Add(this.setTime);
        this.Controls.Add(this.delTime);
        this.Controls.Add(this.checkboxTime);
        this.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel1);
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;
        this.Name = "MainForm";
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.PerformLayout();
        this.tableLayoutPanel2.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.tableLayoutPanel2.PerformLayout();
        this.tableLayoutPanel3.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.tableLayoutPanel3.PerformLayout();
        this.tableLayoutPanel4.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.setTime.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.setTime.PerformLayout();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();
    }
    public System.Windows.Forms.Timer clockTimer;
    System.Windows.Forms.Button addTime;
    System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox setTime;
    System.Windows.Forms.Button addSec;
    System.Windows.Forms.Button subSec;
    System.Windows.Forms.Button addMin;
    System.Windows.Forms.Button subMin;
    System.Windows.Forms.Button addHour;
    System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel4;
    System.Windows.Forms.Label setSecond;
    System.Windows.Forms.Label setMinute;
    System.Windows.Forms.Label setHour;
    System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel3;
    System.Windows.Forms.Button subHour;
    System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel2;
    System.Windows.Forms.Button delTime;
    System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox checkboxTime;
    System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel1;
    System.Windows.Forms.Label second;
    System.Windows.Forms.Label hour;
    System.Windows.Forms.Label minute;
    }
}
```

**MainForm.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace alarmClock
{
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public static int setH = 0;
    public static int setM = 0;
    public static int setS = 0;

    public static DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    public static string time = now.ToLongTimeString();

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    void DelTimeClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    void SubHourClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setH--;
        setHourTime();
    }

    void AddHourClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setH++;
        setHourTime();
    }

    void SubMinClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setM--;
        setMinuteTime();
    }

    void AddMinClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setM++;
        setMinuteTime();
    }

    void SubSecClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setS--;
        setSecondTime();
    }

    void AddSecClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setS++;
        setSecondTime();
    }

    void AddTimeClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    void CheckboxTimeSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    void ClockTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hour.Text = time[0].ToString() + time[1].ToString();
        hour.Update();
        minute.Text = time[3].ToString() + time[4].ToString();
        minute.Update();
        second.Text = time[6].ToString() + time[7].ToString();
        second.Update();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should move your code out of the generated designer file.

Comment: Not your answer, but stay away from the designer.cs. DO NOT write your code there

Comment: I've moved all of my code out of the designer file.

Comment: setHourTime() should be outside designer file. And you do not need an if to print a number. setH.ToString("00")

Answer (score 0):

ClockTimerTick handler copies contents of the `time` variable to the hour, minute, and second controls. And this variable never changes, you only set it once.

Comment: DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    hour.Text = now.Hour.ToString("00");
    minute.Text = now.Minute.ToString("00");
    second.Text = now.Second.ToString("00");

Comment: Thanks for the help, I managed to get it working in the end with:

void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   time.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
  }

So simple but I guess I missed it.